# Game Center score posting/leaderboard creation isn't working

Tags: iphone, xcode, game-center

I'm trying to get games center to work with, no luck. I'm using the Apple sample code.
When I go to view the leaderboard in the app, I see "unable to load" under the leaderboard in game center.

Things I've checked:

- My bundle ID on ITunesConnect is the same as in my info.plist
- That my Leaderboard is set up on iTunesconnect
- That my leaderboard ID is correctly entered into the code
- #import  is included in the .m file

The code I have in my .h file:

```
    int *scoreInt;


}

-(IBAction)subScore;
-(IBAction)showLeader;
```

Code in my .m file:

```
-(IBAction)subScore
{
    {
        GKScore *scoreReporter = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"1234567"] autorelease];
        //in his tuturial value = scoreInt, not a label.

        //try either i_StartPt or finalStarPt
        scoreReporter.value = scoreInt;

        [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error != nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"failed!!!");
                NSLog(scoreInt);
            }
        }];
    }
}
-(IBAction)showLeader
{
    GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
    if (leaderboardController != nil)
    {
        leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES];
    }
}

- (void)leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Any suggestions would be fantastic! I've looked at similar errors on stackoverflow but I haven't found a solution that has worked.

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you signed in the local player?

Also check to make sure you've set everything up according to [Apple's Leaderboard Checklist](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW14).